# Empty decimal tag won't accept '' value, is invalid according to its datatype

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, biztalk

I am getting this error when testing a map:

> The value '' is invalid according to its datatype
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:decimal' - The string '' is not a
>   valid Decimal value.

The tag "LineAmount" is present in the input file, but is empty. I've tried making a "IsBlank" check before outputting the value, but it gives me the same error. The tag is optional and it should be possible not to include a value. Is it not possible to send en empty decimal tag in XSLT?

This is the tag in question:

```
<LineAmount/>
```

Comment: You cannot have self closing tags in angular

Comment: This is not angular. I am doing a Biztalk map in Visual Studio using the visual mapper.

Comment: If  you want to have an empty element you additionally need to use `<LineAmount xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

So, the error is correct as '' (empty string) is not a valid Decimal.

The first thing you need to do is determine *exactly* what the destination value should be, specifically, 0 or not appear at all.

If the destination should always appear and be 0 if the source is empty, you will need to use a Scripting Functoid with a TryParse().

If the destination field should not appear if the source is empty, you can suppress the destination with some Functoids.  For example:

> Source -> Equal (Source & '') -> Logical Not -> Target

This means only include the target if the source is not ''.  You will still link for the value separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a "Value Mapping" functoid to link or not link the LineAmount.

The first argument should be a boolean value that says if the field has value and the second parameter, the LineAmount itself.